# joomla 3.3.0 upgrade from 2.5.20 not getting css in template

Tags: css, joomla

Recently, I have upgraded from joomla 2.5.20 to joomla 3.3.0. After upgrade I faced an error which is related to "remember me" plugin.

I have disabled that plugin from database and that fixed the problem. But after that I followed up that the "control panel" of joomla administrator is not showing the page correctly. It is showing contents without css.

Is it related with "remember me" plugin. I dont think so. But anyone have faced this issue earlier?

Comment: Turn on error repoting to maximum and see if you are getting an error message

Comment: Have turned on the error reporting to maximum. But the issue is in admin panel. When I am in "control panel" after login, it is not getting css. But when I am in for example "module manager", it is getting the css. Any idea what is the reason.

Comment: Most likely it is a fatal error somewhere, probably due to a plugin. Carefully turn off one plugin at a time to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time this breakage happens due to improper update of Database. First try to disable modules. After that try to restructure Database via Extension Manager->Database. You have to try this because , when migrating from 2.x to 3.x , Database structure get slightly changed.

Second of all look at your existing database. New migrations may have added some tables without prefixes that defined by you. This can lead to fatal errors!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most basic problems with upgrading to J3.3 that catches out a large amount of people is breakages to the admin template. It is usually as simple as clearing the Joomla cache (System -> Clear Cache / Purge expired) and browser cache (separate things)

Also if you have moved from J2.5 to J3.3 have you changed your admin template to the J3.3 ISIS template?

Apologies if this is basic info, not meaning to insult, but I have been working with Joomla since is was called Mambo, and that clearing of Joomla cache got me the first time I upgraded to 3 and is on the joomla support forums MANY times!

Comment: No, actually clearing the cache didn't solve the problem. The admin template is still broken. It was by default "ISIS" template activated at admin after the upgrade. Any more ideas?